# why is my backbone router not routing inside this marionette module

Tags: backbone.js, marionette, backbone-routing

I have a marionette module I am starting:

```
my.module('myApp', {
  startWithParent: false,
  define:  
  function (myApp, my, Backbone, Marionette,$, _) {

    var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
                routes: {
                       "howdy": "howdy",
                       "": "first"
                },

                first: function () {
                    console.log("first");
                },
                howdy: function () {
                    console.log("howdy");
                }
        });  

    myApp.on("initialize:after", function(){
      console.log("after");  
    });

    myApp.on('start', function(){
      console.log("start");  
    });

    myApp.addInitializer(function (args) {
        console.log("initialized");
        var router = new Router();
    });
  }
});
```

When I load my application I start my module.

I start, and get initialized correctly.

But I assumed that when I am localhost:8080 or localhost:8080#howdy that the first and howdy methods would run respectively.

What have I done wrong here?

How can I change the above code so that when I load the page the 'first' method runs and when I load the page with the #howdy at the end the howdy method runs?

This should hopefully be doable within the module structure I've already worked out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to start listening to history events with the `History` object:

```
Backbone.history.start();
```

Do this after you've created your routers. More information [here](http://backbonejs.org/#History-start).

Comment: There is something else I don't understand though in the documentation for history:

Comment: There is something else I don't understand though in the documentation for history:  If the server has already rendered the entire page, and you don't want the initial route to trigger when starting History, pass silent: true. My initial route is not triggering ( "": "first") - I put Backbone.history.start(); after starting the router in the initialize method.

Comment: I am also wondering why the initialize:after event does not seem to be firing.

Comment: You might want to check that the route fragment it's routing on is an empty string (for your first route). Add some breakpoints to the `getFragment` function in `Backbone.History` and see what it spits out.

Comment: So it's firing the `start` event but not `initialize:after`?

Comment: yes it's firing start, and initialize but not initialize after cause I never get the message in console.log("after");

Comment: You were right, I had ended up making my 'first' route not empty by mistake.

Comment: That's strange about your events. The `start` function in the `Application` object should be triggering `initialize:after` before `start`. I'd need a bit more information to help there. And it might be worth asking it in another question.